# New mobile chat: Italic text nested in bold text does not render correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design, mobile-web

[This message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27356832#27356832), which uses asterisk characters for both bold and italics with italic text nested within bold text, fails to render correctly in the new mobile chat. The nested italic text renders as italics only when it should be *both* bold and italic. The text is displayed correctly on the desktop site.

```
With IMFT 3D NAND, Mushkin aims to push it down to 12.5¢/GB – **and it's *still* MLC!**
```

Can someone look into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS reset for the new mobile UI was too aggressive, so anything that wasn't not directly contained in `<b>` and `<strong>` wasn't bolded. This is fixed in the next chat build (later today).